# Disable touchs and UI in VideoView in fullscreen kiosk mode?

Tags: android, android-videoview, kiosk-mode

I need to run VideoView in splash kiosk mode.
So I set it to fullscreen (all UI hidden, LOW_PROFILE etc). Mediacontroller not set and not exists. videoview set to not clickable in xml. VideoView OnTouch method overrided. Zorder set to -1. I tried all methods...

**but!**

Any touch of running VideoView shows me bottom navigation bar (back, home etc) on tablet.
System hides it automatically at 3 seconds. I can not override it :(

How to make VideoView in fullscreen - fully untouchable?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, never seen it here.

this totally disables bottom UI on tablet (but leave upper bar on phone)

```
  videoView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE);
```

to hide status on phone just set in activity onCreate as usual:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
```

Comment: No effect on Android 6

Answer (score 0):

Have been fighting with this for a while, and it turns out nothing happens if you set the flags on the VideoView, but works when you do it on the mediaController:

```
mediaController.setSystemUiVisibility(
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
|View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

A remaining problem is that the video now doesn't seem to respond to touch at all, so the media controls are also gone.